# AFrame No mesh.geometry.vertices attribute in version 0.3.0

Tags: aframe

I am trying to recreate the game tutorial from the version 0.2.0 docs using 0.3.0:
https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/guide/building-an-advanced-scene.html

The collider component uses the following statement:

```
var vertices = mesh.geometry.vertices;
```

In 0.3.0 it returns the error:

```
vertices undefined
```

If you print

```
console.log(mesh.geometry);
```

In version 0.2.0 vertices is returned as an attribute of geometry, but in 0.3.0 there is no such attribute.

How should I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

They now default to BufferGeometry.

You can opt-out: `<a-entity geometry="buffer: false">`

Or old data before conversion is also stored in `this.geometry.metadata`.

Comment: If all you need are vertices, you can also get them from a BufferGeometry via `geometry.attributes.position.array`. It will be a flat array, like `[x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, ...]`. [Example](https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-to-cannon/blob/master/index.js#L315-L324).